# Spring injecting SessionFactory or EntityManagerFactory rather EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have my reasons for the switch, but prior I had been **injecting** the EntityManager as such:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "accounts.persistence.unit")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public Session session() {
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

And same for store:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "store.persistence.unit")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public Session session() {
    return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
}
```

The configuration for both these are in a another class and looks like this:

```
@Bean(name= "accounts.persistence.unit")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    return super.buildEntityManagerFactory('accounts.persistence.unit');
}
```

And in super:

```
protected final EntityManagerFactory buildEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnit) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryFactory.setJpaProperties(properties);

    entityManagerFactoryFactory.setPackagesToScan(packages);
    entityManagerFactoryFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnit);
    
    entityManagerFactoryFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    
    return entityManagerFactoryFactory.getObject();
}
```

Same is repeated for **store**.persistence.unit

This works great! However, I now need access to SessionFactory since I really have no use for the **EntityManager** at all other than to unrap to **Session** which in turn unraps to sessionFactory.

**SessionFactory** most of the times then call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` which would again return the session that got us the `sessionFactory`.

However, the reason for this, is because the central implementation details is sessionFactory which might at some points, decide to `sessionFactory.openSession()` to force open a new one.

Since we already came from a session to sessionFactory, this would now result in **two** `sessions` being open.

When we inject EntityManager, a connection is automatically started, or perhaps when a transaction is begun. So forcing a new session using an injected entitymanager will also result in two underlying sessions.

If we instead could inject SessionFactory or EntityManagerFactory that is capable of handling the call, `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` properly then we would be fine.

**That is the question.**

How can I **instead** inject the sessionFactory or entityMangerFactory rather than entityManager, or session ( which i am unable to anyway)?

I can not get it to work with `PersistenceContext`, or `PersistenceUnit` and since `@Autowired` takes no name, I could not inject the specific one I want which what is suggests here:

[See 5. Usage](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring)

When I inject the EnitymanagerFactory **however**, I do get the entityManagerFactory, but that leads to getCurrentSession() not opening a session if there is none, despite having set:

```
properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread")
```

I've tried to also built a **SessionFactory** rather than a **EntityManagerFactory** like this:

```
@Bean(name = "accounts.persitence.unit")
@Override
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return super.buildSessionFactory();
}

protected final SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean ( );
    sessionFactoryFactory.setHibernateProperties ( properties );
    sessionFactoryFactory.setPackagesToScan      ( packages  );

    try {
        sessionFactoryFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new $RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return sessionFactoryFactory.getObject();
}
```

But when I inject it:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = 'accounts.persitence.unit')
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

> Error creating bean with name 'repositoryAccounts' defined in file
> Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified field type [interface
> org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is incompatible with resource type
> [javax.persistence.EntityManager]

And:

> Specified field type [interface org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is incompatible with resource type [javax.persistence.EntityManager]

Which is wierd, since no EntityManager is even mentioned in the code as of that.

I suspect the error, is due to @PersistenceContext requiring an **EntityManager** or EntityManagerFactory hence the error.

Anyone can shed some light on how to use or properly ( and efficiently ) access a SessionFactory that is capable of handling and opening a session on sessionFactory.getCurrentSesson() if there is none?

I also tried:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "accounts.persistence.unit")
SessionFactory session;
```

With error:

> No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: accounts.persistence.unit,store.persistence.unit

Seems it is ignoring the name specified on @PersistenceContext.

Comment: Addressing people as "Idiot" is not appropriate. Not on SO and really nowhere else. I removed the phrase.

Comment: Did you tried inject Session Factory using @Autowire and @Qualifier?? In my case it works well